# install UCMA 3.0 and create a trusted application pool

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, lync, ucma

I am following the [tutorial](https://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/09/installing-ucma-3-0-and-creating-a-lync-server-2010-trusted-application-pool/)

.As explained in the tutorial, I have installed UCMA 3.0 SDK 
Next is, I ran `Run Bootstrapper.exe /BootstrapLocalMgmt /MinCache` successfully.
In the third step, I am trying to run the command   Run Get-CsSite to get the SiteId, but I am getting an error as:

> "Cannot find information about the local domain".

I am not sure about this error. Can somebody help me out with this. I am doing this on an azure machine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your machine is correctly joined to the domain, and meets the other pre-requisites:
You may be missing the configuration store, or the Lync components installation didn't succeed or didn't perform all needed setup properly.

I'd suggest to run the Lync 2010 setup (UI) on that machine, in order to have it joining the Lync farm properly (I use to do in this way), and get the configuration store as well.
My suggestion is to perform Step 3 and 4 from the following article:
http://lyncinsider.com/conferencing/how-to-add-new-servers-to-lync-20-tasks-every-lync-administrator-must-know/